# Best Timer for using in a Windows service

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I need to create some windows service which will execute every N period of time.
The question is:
Which timer control should I use: `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer` one? Does it influence on something?

I am asking because I heard many evidences to non correct work of `System.Timers.Timer` in windows services.
Thank you.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Both [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) and [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) will work for services.

The timers you want to avoid are [`System.Web.UI.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx) and [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx), which are respectively for ASP applications and WinForms. Using those will cause the service to load an additional assembly which is not really needed for the type of application you are building.

Use [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) like the following example (also, make sure that you use a class level variable to prevent garbage collection, as stated in Tim Robinson's answer):

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Timer1
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Normally, the timer is declared at the class level,
        // so that it stays in scope as long as it is needed.
        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method,  
        // KeepAlive must be used to prevent the JIT compiler 
        // from allowing aggressive garbage collection to occur 
        // before the method ends. (See end of method.)
        //System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use
        // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring
        // before the method ends.
        //GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is 
    // raised.
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }
}

/* This code example produces output similar to the following:

Press the Enter key to exit the program.
The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2007 8:42:27 PM
The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2007 8:42:29 PM
The Elapsed event was raised at 5/20/2007 8:42:31 PM
...
 */
```

If you choose [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), you can use as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class TimerExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent     = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        StatusChecker  statusChecker = new StatusChecker(10);

        // Create the delegate that invokes methods for the timer.
        TimerCallback timerDelegate = 
            new TimerCallback(statusChecker.CheckStatus);

        // Create a timer that signals the delegate to invoke 
        // CheckStatus after one second, and every 1/4 second 
        // thereafter.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Creating timer.\n", 
            DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.fff"));
        Timer stateTimer = 
                new Timer(timerDelegate, autoEvent, 1000, 250);

        // When autoEvent signals, change the period to every 
        // 1/2 second.
        autoEvent.WaitOne(5000, false);
        stateTimer.Change(0, 500);
        Console.WriteLine("\nChanging period.\n");

        // When autoEvent signals the second time, dispose of 
        // the timer.
        autoEvent.WaitOne(5000, false);
        stateTimer.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("\nDestroying timer.");
    }
}

class StatusChecker
{
    int invokeCount, maxCount;

    public StatusChecker(int count)
    {
        invokeCount  = 0;
        maxCount = count;
    }

    // This method is called by the timer delegate.
    public void CheckStatus(Object stateInfo)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Checking status {1,2}.", 
            DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.fff"), 
            (++invokeCount).ToString());

        if(invokeCount == maxCount)
        {
            // Reset the counter and signal Main.
            invokeCount  = 0;
            autoEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Both examples comes from the MSDN pages.

Comment: Why do you suggest:         GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);, aTimer is instance variable right, so for example if it is instance variable of form, there will always be reference to it as long as there is form, isn't it?

Answer (score 37):

Don't use a service for this.  Create a normal application and create a scheduled task to run it.

This is the commonly held best practice.  [Jon Galloway agrees with me.  Or maybe its the other way around.](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx)  Either way, the fact is that it is not best practices to create a windows service to perform an intermittent task run off a timer.

> **"If you're writing a Windows Service that runs a timer, you should re-evaluate your solution."**
>
> –Jon Galloway, ASP.NET MVC community program manager, author, part time superhero

Comment: If your service is intended to run all day, then perhaps a service makes sense rather than a scheduled task. Or, having a service might simplify admin and logging for an infrastructure group that is not as savvy as the application team. However, questioning the assumption that a service is required is entirely valid, and these negatively ratings are undeserved. +1 to both.

Comment: Windows scheduled task is extremely buggy. Windows services is a lot more reliable..

Comment: @m.r. Nonsense. Scheduled tasks are a core part of the OS. Please keep your FUD to yourself.

Comment: @will - That has nothing to do with it. Yes, they are - but if you're going to tell me that because they are a core part of the OS that they are rock solid, that would be silly. Yes, windows is such a stable operating system.

Comment: @M.R.: I'm not an evangelist, I'm a realist.  And reality has taught me that scheduled tasks aren't "extremely buggy."  It is, in fact, up to you as the person who made that claim to support it.  Otherwise, all you are doing is spreading fear, uncertainty and doubt.

Comment: I hate to wade into the mire here, but i have to defend M.R. a little bit.  I have several critical applications running in my company that are windows console apps.  I have used Windows Task Scheduler for running all of them.  On at least 5 occasions now, we have had a problem where the Scheduler Service "got confused" somehow. Tasks didn't execute and some were in a strange state.  The only solution was a reboot of the server or stop and start of the Scheduler service.  Not something I can do without admin rights and not acceptable in a production environment.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: @SpaceCowboy74: So, is that the norm, or just something that happened to you on one particular server?

Comment: It's actually happened to me on a few servers (3 so far).  Won't say it's the norm though.  Just saying sometimes it's not bad to implement your own method of doing something.

Comment: What should I use, if the interval to time for, is variable and configurable?

Comment: @Nick: Depends.  If you need, say, a website where people can change the schedule, then a service.  Or, if it is configured once per install, or only very rarely, then a scheduled task is fine.

Comment: Just a thought, but what if your service is dependent on scheduling and some uninformed sys admin migrates it to a new server but forgets to migrate scheduled tasks?

Comment: "A service application is designed to be long running. Therefore, it usually polls or monitors something in the system." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: It’s funny that you suggest using another service that uses timers(contradicting ) to run a console app, rather than role your own. Also, scheduled tasks is NOT a core part of the OS, it is just another service that has been introduced into the OS. It was introduced into windows 2000. Services on the other hand IS a core part of the OS. In my many years I've witnessed many times when the Scheduler Service data has gotten corrupt and NO tasks would run, and the only fix was a fresh OS rebuild. The question comes down to if you want to rely on another service to run your app or create your own.

Answer (score 7):

Either one should work OK. In fact, System.Threading.Timer uses System.Timers.Timer internally.

Having said that, it's easy to misuse System.Timers.Timer. If you don't store the Timer object in a variable somewhere, then it is liable to be garbage collected. If that happens, your timer will no longer fire. Call the Dispose method to stop the timer, or use the System.Threading.Timer class, which is a slightly nicer wrapper.

What problems have you seen so far?

Comment: Makes me wonder why a Windows Phone app can only access System.Threading.Timer.

Comment: windows phones probably have a lighter version of the framework, having all of that extra code to be able to use both methods is probably not needed so it is not included. I think that Nick's answer, gives a better reason for why Windows phones don't have access to `System.Timers.Timer` because it won't handle the Exceptions thrown to it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with previous comment that might be best to consider a different approach.  My suggest would be write a console application and use the windows scheduler:

This will:

- Reduce plumbing code that replicates scheduler behaviour
- Provide greater flexibility in terms
  of scheduling behaviour (e.g. only
  run on weekends) with all scheduling logic abstracted from application code
- Utilise the command line arguments
  for parameters without having to
  setup configuration values in config
  files etc
- Far easier to debug/test during development
- Allow a support user to execute by invoking
  the console application directly
  (e.g. useful during support
  situations)

Comment: But this requires a logged on user? So service is maybe better if it will run 24/7 on a server.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated both `System.Threading.Timer` and `System.Timers.Timer` will work. The big difference between the two is that `System.Threading.Timer` is a wrapper arround the other one.

> `System.Threading.Timer` will have more exception handling while
>   `System.Timers.Timer` will swallow all the exceptions.

This gave me big problems in the past so I would always use 'System.Threading.Timer' and still handle your exceptions very well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a little old but it came in handy for a specific scenario I had and I thought it worth while to note that there is another reason why `System.Threading.Timer` might be a good approach. 
When you have to periodically execute a Job that might take a long time and you want to ensure that the entire waiting period is used between jobs or if you don't want the job to run again before the previous job has finished in the case where the  job takes longer than the timer period. 
You could use the following:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;

    public partial class TimerExampleService : ServiceBase
    {
        private AutoResetEvent AutoEventInstance { get; set; }
        private StatusChecker StatusCheckerInstance { get; set; }
        private Timer StateTimer { get; set; }
        public int TimerInterval { get; set; }

        public CaseIndexingService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TimerInterval = 300000;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            AutoEventInstance = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            StatusCheckerInstance = new StatusChecker();

            // Create the delegate that invokes methods for the timer.
            TimerCallback timerDelegate =
                new TimerCallback(StatusCheckerInstance.CheckStatus);

            // Create a timer that signals the delegate to invoke 
            // 1.CheckStatus immediately, 
            // 2.Wait until the job is finished,
            // 3.then wait 5 minutes before executing again. 
            // 4.Repeat from point 2.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Creating timer.\n",
                DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.fff"));
            //Start Immediately but don't run again.
            StateTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, AutoEventInstance, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
            while (StateTimer != null)
            {
                //Wait until the job is done
                AutoEventInstance.WaitOne();
                //Wait for 5 minutes before starting the job again.
                StateTimer.Change(TimerInterval, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            //If the Job somehow takes longer than 5 minutes to complete then it wont matter because we will always wait another 5 minutes before running again.
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            StateTimer.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class StatusChecker
        {

            public StatusChecker()
            {
            }

            // This method is called by the timer delegate.
            public void CheckStatus(Object stateInfo)
            {
                AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Start Checking status.",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.fff"));
                //This job takes time to run. For example purposes, I put a delay in here.
                int milliseconds = 5000;
                Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
                //Job is now done running and the timer can now be reset to wait for the next interval
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Done Checking status.",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.fff"));
                autoEvent.Set();
            }
        }
```