# Windows service scheduled execution

Tags: c#, windows-services

If I have a Windows Service that needs to execute a task every 30 seconds which is better to use; the Timer() class or a loop that executes the task then sleeps for a number of seconds?

```
class MessageReceiver 
{
    public MessageReceiver()
    {
    }

    public void CommencePolling()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try 
            {
                this.ExecuteTask();     
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // log the exception
            }
        }
    }

    public void ExecutedTask()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

class MessageReceiver 
{
    public MessageReceiver()
    {
    }

    public void CommencePolling()
    {
        var timer = new Timer()
            {
                AutoReset = true,
                Interval = 30000,
                Enabled = true
            };

        timer.Elapsed += Timer_Tick;    
    }

    public void Timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        try 
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // log the exception
        }
    }
}
```

The windows service will create an instance of the MessageReciever class and execute the CommencePolling method on a new thread.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099516/for-a-windows-service-which-is-better-a-wait-spin-or-a-timer, which I found by searching "service timer".

Comment: @John thanks. I tried searching for "Windows Service Timer" but couldn't find anything. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it really depends on your requirement.

**case 1.** 
Suppose you want to run `this.ExecuteTask()` every five minutes starting from 12:00AM (i.e., 12:00, 12:05, ...) and suppose the execution time of `this.ExecuteTask()` varies (for example, from 30 sec to 2 min), maybe using timer instead of Thread.Sleep() seems to be an easier way of doing it (at least for me).

However, you can achieve this behavior with `Thread.Sleep()` as well by calculating the offset while taking timestamps on a thread wake-up and on a completion of `this.ExecuteTask()`.

**case 2.** 
Suppose you want to perform the task in the next 5 min just after completion of `this.ExecuteTask()`, using `Thread.Sleep()` seems to be easier.  Again, you can achieve this behavior with a timer as well by reseting the timer every time while calculating offsets on every time `this.ExecuteTask()` completes.

**Note1**, for the case 1, you should be very careful in the following scenario: what if `this.ExecuteTask()` sometimes takes more than the period (i.e. it starts at 12:05 and completes 12:13 in the example above).

1. What does this mean to your application and how will it be handled?

   a.  Total failure - abort the service or abort the current(12:05) execution at 12:10 and launch 12:10 execution.
   b. Not a big deal (skip 12:10 one and run `this.ExecuteTask()` at 12:15).

   c. Not a big deal, but need to launch 12:10 execution immediately after 12:05 task finishes (what if it keeps taking more than 5 min??).

   d. Need to launch 12:10 execution even though 12:05 execution is currently running.

   e. anything else?
2. For the policy you select above, does your choice of implementation (either timer or `Thread.Sleep()`) easy to support your policy?

**Note2**. There are several timers you can use in .NET.  Please see the following document (even though it's bit aged, but it seems to be a good start): [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything else during that ten second wait? Using Thread.sleep would block, preventing you from doing other things. From a performance point of view I don't think you'd see too much difference, but I would avoid using Thread.sleep myself.

There are three timers to choose from - System.Windows.Forms.Timer is implemented on the main thread whereas System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer are creating seperate threads.

Answer (score 0):

I believe both methods are equivalent. There will be a thread either way: either because you create one, or because the library implementing the Timer class creates one.

Using the Timer class might be slightly more less expensive resource-wise, since the thread implementing timers probably monitors other timeouts as well.

Answer (score 0):

I this the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Not answered by me but John Saunders (above)... the answer can be found here [For a windows service, which is better, a wait-spin or a timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099516/for-a-windows-service-which-is-better-a-wait-spin-or-a-timer)