# Send E-mail reminder with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have a book lending system written with ASP.NET, VB.NET and LINQ to SQL. I want the web app to send the e-mail reminder about the due date to the borrower before the book is over-due. Should I write a desktop app to check the due date or there's another way around to send e-mail reminder?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much traffic the site sees, you could make use of HTTP Cache like how StackOverflow does.  You can read about it in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/).  Although the blog appears to be down right now, so here's the [Google cache](http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:eOZ-i8EwSCMJ:blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/+stackoverflow+http+cache+tasks&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&lr=lang_en).

Answer (score 3):

Write a service or a console app that is run with Windows scheduled tasks, then have that consult the database for due dates, and send out emails accordingly.

Don't use desktop interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled service. If your LINQ backend is a decent database (like SQL Server), you can schedule a task with the SQL Server Agent and have it fire off emails when necessary. That could be accomplished via script, or a CLR SQL assembly (effectively, a .net assembly that plugs into the SQL server).

Answer (score 1):

I think a windows service is suitable for this task. Take a look at that question about [using timer with a windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer).

Answer (score 1):

If you write a windows desktop app then it will not run if you don't login in. You can write a windows service and install it in the server and it can send out reminder emails.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) an open source job scheduler for the .NET platform. You can use it to perform scheduled tasks inside of a Windows service. For example, you could schedule a task to run every morning and have it query your database and then send out an email if the due date of a book is within the range.

Answer (score 0):

A great little starter tutorial i have bookmarked for windows services [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp)