# Is there a way to sleep unless a message is received?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, service

I'm working in a service whose main loop looks like this:

```
while (fServer.ServerState = ssStarted) and (Self.Terminated = false) do
begin
  Self.ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(false);
  ProcessFiles;
  Sleep(3000);      
end;
```

ProcessRequests is a lot like `Application.ProcessMessages`.  I can't pass `true` to it because if I do then it blocks until a message is received from Windows, and ProcessFiles won't run, and it has to run continually.  The Sleep is there to keep the CPU usage down.

This works just fine until I try to shut down the service from Windows's service management list.  When I hit Stop, it sends a message and expects to get a response almost immediately, and if it's in the middle of that Sleep command, Windows will give me an error that the service didn't respond to the Stop command.

So what I need is to say "Sleep for 3000 or until you receive a message, whichever comes first."  I'm sure there's an API for that, but I'm not sure what it is.  Does anyone know?

Comment: I do exactly this in my services, but keep the sleeps short. The CPU is still kept down by the scheduler. Try sleep(500)

Comment: You want to sleep until you receive a message, in a background thread, or you want to freeze your foreground thread? enlighten me here.

Comment: You could try SleepEx, or WaitForMultipleObjects, as Jeroen suggests. SleepEx is designed for interruptable sleeps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timer to run ProcessFiles instead of hacking it into main application loop. Then ProcessFiles will run in the interval you want and the messages will be processed correctly, not taking 100 % CPU.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and it didn't work.  I took it out and replaced it with the sleep loop, which I agree is an ugly hack.  But I just tried it again with a timer, (a lot's changed since I did that) and now it works.  Go figure.

Comment: This is not appropriate for a service

Comment: @mj2008: This wasn't supposed to be a service at all, originally. But you know how scope creep is... :(

Comment: There are timers that work well with services, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer (it's not a Delphi code though). I think the Delphi timer could work fine anyway.

Comment: Maybe in this case, but as soon as you start using threads, the TTimer has a bag of surprises for you.

Comment: Then you depend on mainthread regular availability. Not a good thing in busy apps.

Comment: It so happens that the periodic TTimer firing in a VCL app is a lurking source of really fun stuff. Especially come the day you figure you should add a call to Application.ProcessMessages somewhere in your application code.  Remember this day, when the next weird bug shows up.

Answer (score 11):

This kind of stuff is hard to get right, so I usually start at the API documentation at MSDN.

The [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032(VS.85).aspx) documention specifically directs to [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242(v=VS.85).aspx) for these kinds of situations:

> Use caution when calling the wait
>   functions and code that directly or
>   indirectly creates windows. If a
>   thread creates any windows, it must
>   process messages. Message broadcasts
>   are sent to all windows in the system.
>   A thread that uses a wait function
>   with no time-out interval may cause
>   the system to become deadlocked. Two
>   examples of code that indirectly
>   creates windows are DDE and the
>   [CoInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543(v=VS.85).aspx) function. Therefore, if
>   you have a thread that creates
>   windows, use [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242(v=VS.85).aspx)
>   or [MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684245(v=VS.85).aspx), rather
>   than `WaitForSingleObject`.

In [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242(v=VS.85).aspx), you have a `dwWakeMask` parameter specifying on which queued messages to return, and a table describing the masks you can use.

**Edit** because of comment by [Warren P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84704/warren-p):

If your main loop can be continued because of a [ReadFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365468(v=VS.85).aspx), [WriteFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365748(v=VS.85).aspx) or [QueueUserAPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684954(v=VS.85).aspx), then you can use [SleepEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686307(VS.85).aspx).

--jeroen

Comment: This is the smart way to go. The other ways are not really "waiting" in a background thread, they are periodically doing something in a foreground thread. These two things are not alternatives for doing the same thing, they are radically different things. Use a thread or don't use a thread, but if you're using a thread, and waiting on a message, you do need it to be interruptable. SleepEx is also interruptable.

Answer (score 8):

MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() is the way to go, ie:

```
while (fServer.ServerState = ssStarted) and (not Self.Terminated) do 
begin 
  ProcessFiles; 
  if MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, nil, FALSE, 3000, QS_ALLINPUT) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
    Self.ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(false); 
end;
```

If you want to call ProcessFiles() at 3 second intervals regardless of any messages arriving, then you can use a waitable timer for that, ie:

```
var
  iDue: TLargeInteger;
  hTimer: array[0..0] of THandle;
begin
  iDue := -30000000; // 3 second relative interval, specified in nanoseconds
  hTimer[0] := CreateWaitableTimer(nil, False, nil);
  SetWaitableTimer(hTimer[0], iDue, 0, nil, nil, False);
  while (fServer.ServerState = ssStarted) and (not Self.Terminated) do 
  begin 
    // using a timeout interval so the loop conditions can still be checked periodically
    case MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, hTimer, False, 1000, QS_ALLINPUT) of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0:
      begin
        ProcessFiles;
        SetWaitableTimer(hTimer[0], iDue, 0, nil, nil, False);
      end;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0+1: Self.ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(false);
    end;
  end;
  CancelWaitableTimer(hTimer[0]);
  CloseHandle(hTimer[0]);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a TTimer in a multithreaded application with strange results, so now i use Events.

```
while (fServer.ServerState = ssStarted) and (Self.Terminated = false) do
begin
  Self.ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(false);
  ProcessFiles;

  if ExitEvent.WaitFor(3000) <> wrTimeout then
    Exit;   
 end;
```

You create the event with

```
ExitEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');
```

Now the last thing is to fire the event in case of service stop. I think the Stop event of the service is the right place to put this.

```
ExitEvent.SetEvent;
```

I use this code for an cleanup thread in my DB connections pooling system, but it should work well in your case too.

Comment: That suffers from the same problem as the original - it is waiting the full 3 seconds since ExitEvent is not able to be signaled until ProcessRequests() is called to process the SCM's stop request.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sleep for 3 full seconds to keep the CPU usage low.  Even something like Sleep(500) should keep your usage pretty low (if there are no messages waiting to process it should blow through the loop pretty quick and hit the sleep again.  If your loop takes a few ms to run it still means your thread is spending the vast majority of time in sleep.

That being said, your code may benefit from some refactoring.  You say you don't want ProcessRequests to block waiting for a message?  The only other thing in that loop is ProcessFiles.  If that is dependent on the message being processed then why can't it block?  And if it's not dependent on the message being processed then can it be split onto another thread?  (the previous suggestion of firing ProcessFiles via a timer is an excellent suggestion on how to do this).

Answer (score 0):

Use an TEvent that you signal when the thread should wake up. Then block on the tevent (using waitformultiple as Jeroen says if you have multiple events to wait on)

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to move ProcessFiles to a seperate thread? In your MainThread you just wait for messages and when the service is being terminated you terminate the ProcessFiles thread.

Comment: Already got that covered.  ProcessFiles basically just looks to see if there are any files to be processed and hands them off to another thread.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: That doesn't hold you off to move ProcessFiles to another thread, or maybe let the file processing thread call ProcessFiles itself after it is done.