# windows services is working only when messagebox.show is used How to avoid it

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

This is my code

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timAutoUpdate.Enabled = true;
    MessageBox.Show("started");
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    timAutoUpdate.Enabled = false;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Service stopped");
}

private void timAutoUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ticked");
}
```

Its showing message "Ticked" after starting event.If i delete messagebox in Onstart event then  Tick event is not working.Its not showing any message.Please specify the reason behind it.I just kept simple message box in Tick event instead of my code.Please tell me the way to achieve it.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timAutoUpdate.Enabled = true;
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    timAutoUpdate.Enabled = false;
}

private void timAutoUpdate_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ticked");
}
```

Comment: from Vista up services can't show UI. Don't attempt to show UI from a service.

Comment: If i didn't show that UI Tick event is not firing.:(

Comment: You are probably using a UI timer by mistake. Use a timer appropriate for services.

Comment: Use either [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) or [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), **not** `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Related question: [Windows service and timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer). Obligatory comment: you probably shouldn't be creating a service in the first place. In 83.7% of cases, a standard application that doesn't show a window is a preferable and simpler alternative.

Comment: Presently i have changed my "System.windows.Forms.Timer" to "System.Timers.Timer   "

Answer (score 0):

What timer are you using? is it System.Windows.Forms.Timer?

if this is the case, you need to change it because this timer does not work with Windows service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Try this code:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        scheduleTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(AutoTick), null, 0, 3000);
        eventLogEmail.WriteEntry("Test");
    }
    private void AutoTick(object state)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ticked")
    }
```

Comment: You were doing great until you called MessageBox. Don't do so in a service!