# how to have a function run inside a service every 10 minutes?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service running, inside this i want to run a function every then minutes.
I have found some code but it doesn't seem to work?
I have a logger and it does not seem to go into the timer_Elapsed function ever?

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
       // SmartImportService.WebService.WebServiceSoapClient test = new WebService.WebServiceSoapClient();
       // test.Import();
         log.Info("Info - Service Started");
        _timer = new Timer(10 * 60 * 1000); // every 10 minutes??
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        log.Info("Info - Check time");
        DateTime startAt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(48);
        if (_lastRun < startAt && DateTime.Now >= startAt)
        {
            // stop the timer 
            _timer.Stop();               

            try
            {
                log.Info("Info - Import");
                SmartImportService.WebService.WebServiceSoapClient test = new WebService.WebServiceSoapClient();
                test.Import();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                log.Error("This is my error - ", ex);
            }

            _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to call start on the Timer?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer

Comment: why? `DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(48);`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to start the timer:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
     log.Info("Info - Service Started");
    _timer = new Timer(10 * 60 * 1000); // every 10 minutes
    _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    _timer.Start(); // <- important
}
```

Comment: For the 10 minutes, I prefer to use `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds;` instead of `10 * 60 * 1000`

Answer (score 4):

I don't see `_timer.Start()`, that should be your problem.

Answer (score 3):

[Daniel Hilgarth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10206031/65358) is correct - the main issue is that you never call Start on the timer.

That being said, you might want to also consider using the Windows Task Scheduler instead of a service with a timer.  This allows you to schedule the task to run every 10 minutes, but also change the schedule whenever desired without a compilation change.

Answer (score 3):

I need this functionality also. That is, my C# windows service must check email every 10 minutes. I stripped down some logic to make the code more effective, as follows :

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            try
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(Program.EventLogName, "Checking emails " + _count++);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(Program.EventLogName, "This is my error " + ex.Message);
            }
            _timer.Start();
        }
```

The timer_elapsed method indeed will be call every 10 minutes, starting from the first _timer.start(), which you miss it by the way. I haven't done any checking of the _lastRun and startAt. I don't think we need it

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the `timer`,

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
       // SmartImportService.WebService.WebServiceSoapClient test = new WebService.WebServiceSoapClient();
       // test.Import();
         log.Info("Info - Service Started");
        _timer = new Timer(10 * 60 * 1000); // every 10 minutes??
            _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
_timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        log.Info("Info - Check time");
        DateTime startAt = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9).AddMinutes(48);
        if (_lastRun < startAt && DateTime.Now >= startAt)
        {
            // stop the timer 
            _timer.Stop();               

            try
            {
                log.Info("Info - Import");
                SmartImportService.WebService.WebServiceSoapClient test = new WebService.WebServiceSoapClient();
                test.Import();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                log.Error("This is my error - ", ex);
            }

            _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }
```