# Console Application to Service - do I have to note something?

Tags: c#, .net, service, timer

I'm coding a console application that is reading and writing some stuff at different intervals during the day. I want this later (if its "final") as a service. For now a simple console application is better (that's how I thought) because its easier to use and I can see the result without having to register/start/end the service. Is it easy to later, if I'm done with  the testing, just create a new service project and copy the code from the console application?

I heard now that we should not use `Timer` in a service. But I'm using `System.Threading.Timer` in my console application a lot. Does it mean that I'll be in trouble? Is it this *"testing on console app and then using it on service"* thing not a good idea? Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you hear that you should not use `Timer` in your service?

Comment: @DanPuzey"If you're writing a Windows Service that runs a timer, you should re-evaluate your solution." - in this thrad(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer) Will did post that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Windows service and Right click->Properties and change Output Type as Console Application do your developement.Once you have done with development change back Output Type as Windows Application.

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) to know deep about the both timers.

Comment: That's very interesting information but does not answer OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `System.Threading.Timer` is that there's no easy way to start/stop the timer. And because of that, you can't realiably use it for tasks which could possibly take LONGER than the timer interval.

Switch to `System.Timers.Timer` instead:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/05/systemwindowsformstimer-vs.html

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for you - is to try [Application As Service](http://www.application-as-service.com/) software

You can launch every application as a service.