# Windows Service calling a web page

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

I think I'm not understanding something about how asp or windows services works.

I'm trying to create scheduled reporting on my asp.net project.  I have a windows service running on my local machine right now, later it will run on a dedicated server.  It is supposed to request an ASP page every couple minutes, and on being requested the web page currently emails me on page_load.  Here is the code I use in the windows service to call the web page.

```
HttpWebRequest request= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
request.Method = "GET";
response = request.GetResponse();
reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I know it gets this far, because I've been having the service email me too, at every step.  However, the web page does nothing when the service requests the page.  If I paste the address of the asp page into my browser then I get an email from the page. The ASP.NET website is running in VS debug mode on my computer.  Does the service have to open up a browser first?

If a browser is required for the page to work, is there a way for me to run code in my asp project without opening a browser at regular intervals?

Comment: Have you called myReq.GetResponse()?

Comment: I added some code, I wasn't..but now I am.  Same deal.

Comment: Try creating a new method on your page to send the email and decorate it with [WebMethod] and then call `.../<your_page.aspx>/<web_method>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I think it is me who has misunderstood - using a [WebMethod] will allow you to target that method explicitly, but you can't display something in your Windows Service. It sounds like you need something like JavaScript's `setInterval()` to fire an AJAX call every 120000 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (almost) cannot open browser from windows a service, as well as it's just wrong to do this. 
Can you move your email sending to service?

Comment: Well, the emails are just a placeholder for some visible action, I want to run a bunch of reports.

Comment: Can you post also your asp code? May be this caused by IsPostBack verification? Cause each httprequest is new .page load (not postback).

Comment: Are you saying it should work, then?  I don't have a postback check on my page, though.

Comment: It prbobably can work. If you place breakpoint inside page _load - do you stop there?

Comment: I decided to just leave the scheduling on the web-app, and have the windows service do all the hard work.

Comment: Yes, its best practice design! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can simply call your webpage with the task scheduler

```
//Create a new scheduled task to open a browser eg: internet explorer then right
//click properties, in the run window type in with the quotes an example
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.mywebsite.com/something/myactionpage.chtml" 
//If you want to open the page with another browser, just change the first path
```

or like that

[Best Timer for using in a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer/246719#246719)

Comment: Works for me as a simple, direct solution.