# Windows service and make it run from 10 A.M to 10 P.M every day with interval

Tags: c#, service

I have a .NET EXE. I want it to set it as a Windows service and make it run from 10 A.M. to 10 P.M. every day with interval of every 3 hrs: 10 A. M, 1 P.M, 4 P.M, 7 P.M, and 10 P.M.

How this can be done? Please help me. There is a method inside the EXE, which needs to contact the database and get the count of the table.

Note: The values of timing are tend to change , it comes from the back end. I mean the from time 10 A.M and thru time 10. PM and frequency 3 hrs. So that they can change according to they needs.

Comment: Why don't you just set it up to run from Task Scheduler at these times? If it's running periodically, then it doesn't sound like a service to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows service and timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a service for this (it's not what services are designed to do).

Use a Windows Scheduled Task for this, and have it run your normal executable at the times you need it to be run. You can do this using the [`Task Scheduler`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) (in `Start->Programs->Accessories->Administrative Tools`).

Comment: No, the values of timing are tend to change , it comes from the back end. I mean the  from time 10 A.M and thru time 10. PM and frequency 3 hrs. So that they can change according to they needs.

Comment: Then they can change the scheduling, and your interface makes the changes using the `Task Scheduler API`. A service is the wrong solution. (And that wasn't the question you asked, which about how to "make it run from 10 A.M. to 10 P.M. every day with interval of every 3 hrs: 10 A. M, 1 P.M, 4 P.M, 7 P.M, and 10 P.M.", which is what I answered. If you have a different question now, post a new question - once you've received answers, it's not proper to change the question. :-)