# Windows Service timing C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have built a Windows Service which on start builds a list of file paths from a specified directory. I then do some processing on those files and delete them. My question is how often will the service build this list? Can we specify a time interval when this service would look into the directory and build the list?

OR

Is it better that I create a console application and assign it to a scheduler?

Comment: The service will build the list as often as you make it. You can add a `Timer` to the service to rebuild the list at an interval that you desire. It is not better to create a console application and assign it to a scheduler. It is not worse either.

Comment: See `FileSystemWatcher` for an alternate approach.

Comment: What's wrong with a FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: Yes, you can specify a time interval to do processing.  A simple loop with a sleep delay in it will suffice for that.  But without knowing what your requirements actually are, I don't know how anyone could offer more.

Comment: @KeithPayne A background process dumps about 3K files at a time. I do a DB processing of each file. Would not like to use a FileSystemWatcher which gets activated on seeing a single file. I would then need 3K DB connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a timer in the application and run your method whenever you like. See this question for a good answer.

[Best Timer for using in a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer)

Some other useful MSDN on building a service, including notes on `OnStart` and `OnStop`, which you might want to take advantage of.

[ServiceBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xh5cfw0)

@Marius also makes a great point about the `FileSystemWatcher` which a great and often overlooked piece of .Net... [FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032170/726986)

Comment: This is not an accurate description of a windows service.

Comment: Apologies... you are right. I have edited it out. The console app is usually just where people tend to start when they are going to build a new service, in my experience anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a perfect use case for a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) which "listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes." By using it, you avoid having to manually schedule file or directory checks.

Comment: Without knowing what the purpose of his application is, how do you know that real-time monitoring is a perfect solution?

Comment: @CareyGregory I don't, thus "most likely" and not "definitely".

Comment: @MariusSchulz A background process dumps about 3K files at a time. I do a DB processing of each file. Would not like to use a FileSystemWatcher which gets activated on seeing a single file. I would then need 3K DB connections.