# VB.Net Self Deletion after 5 days

Tags: vb.net, self-destruction

Im have to execute the following code.

```
Dim Info As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
Info.Arguments = "/C ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > Nul & Del """ & Application.ExecutablePath.ToString & """"    
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Info.CreateNoWindow = True
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe"
Process.Start(Info)`
```

The code will delete the file on execution. How can I code my program so the function is called 5 days after first execution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe windows schedule will call your exe file each 5 days

Comment: but is there a way to code the program so it keeps track of the date of first execution?

Comment: using timer and keep your program running all the time

Answer (score 0):

you might do the following

1- create a windows service application, check this link to get more information
[Developing Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6(v=vs.110).aspx)

2- use timer , check this link to get more information

[Windows service and timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer)

hope this will help you

Comment: @AliHaider i changed the first url for more details

Comment: here a sample of how to create a simple windows service using vs2010 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106742/Creating-a-simple-Windows-Service , hope it will help you