# How to send a mail every 5 mins using schedulers in asp.net (without using window service)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks

Hi I want to send a mail every 5 mins using schedulers in c#,but I don't want to use windows service.how to send a mail every 5 minits. pleae anyone help me.

Comment: give hangfire a look. http://hangfire.io/

Comment: You can use timer to do this.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Mishra please give me any sample code

Comment: @Anit: Create an console application (.exe) and Configure it with windows task scheduler.

Comment: I suggest you check http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/best-timer-for-using-in-a-windows-service

Answer (score 2):

We obviously are not going to write code for you, but please have a look at this suggestion:

> - Write your Console Application that sends Emails.
> - For this have a look at the classes SmtpClient and MailMessage
> - You can also configure Log4Net with an EmailAppender to send Mails
> - Schedule a Task in "Windows Scheduler" to call the Console App every 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple console application which get's started by the windows task scheduler every 5 minutes. This would be the simplest and most stable way.