# Timer and a Windows Serice c#

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

i'm facing a strange problem with a Timer in a Windows service. is my first windows service, so for start to learn i decide to create a service that each 10 seconds write in a .txt file what time is it. 
i add the timer but looks like the timer never start.
can you help me to understand where i'm wrong?
here my code:

```
namespace testtimer
{
    public partial class TestTimer : ServiceBase
    {
        public TestTimer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Interval = 10000;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string date = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
            StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Test\testtimer.txt", true);

            wr.WriteLine("\n" + "The Time is:" + "\t" + date);
            wr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

where i'm wrong?

thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: timer.Tick += timer_Tick; perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am guessing you are using a `Windows.Forms` timer (the component one, that you drag onto your design surface)....this needs a "window" and "message loop" in order to be able to process/receive the actual timer tick event.

When you're an NT service....you don't have a window...you're just a bit of code that has entry points that get called by the SCM (Service Control Manager).

You need to use a different type of timer that uses a thread, and will call back a function.

- [Best Timer for using in a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/best-timer-for-using-in-a-windows-service)

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is why i was testing the same functionality on a windows form and was working and in a service no...thanks for your time and for your help :)....Patrick